# What does $D(D(f))=D(f)=C(D(f))$ it mean in the category of generalized monoid.

Tags: category-theory, notation, definition, monoid, functors

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes

In chapter 7 of Arbib and Manes about Functors.  The authors introduce the category of generalised monoid as motivation and precursor to introducing functors.

1. We have seen that a one-object category is a monoid, let us now see ia sense in which any category is a $\textit{generalized}$ monoid.  Given $\textbf{K},$ let $$\textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}=\coprod_{A,B\in {Obj}\textbf{K}}\textbf{K}(A,B)$$ be the collection of all $\textbf{K}-$morphisms.  Composition definees a $\textit{partial}$ function  $$\textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}\times\textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}\to\textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}:(f,g)\mapsto g\circ f.$$

Let us see how we may recapture the identities of $\textbf{K}$ from this function:  We say that $u$ is an identity if $g\circ u=g$ whenever $g\circ u$ is defined, and if $u\circ f=f$ whenever $u\circ f$ is defined.  As before, each $f$ has exactly one identity $u$ such that $u\circ f$ is defined, call it $C(f)$ for the identity of the $\textit{codomain}$ of $f$; and exactly one $v$ such that $f\circ v$ is defined, call it $D(f)$ for the $\textit{domain}$ of $f.$  Thus our partial function $\textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}\times \textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}} \to \textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}$ satisfies the conditions:

$1.$  There are total functions $$C,D: \textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}\to \text{identities of } \textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}$$

for which

$$D(D(f))=D(f)=C(D(f));$$
$$\quad D(C(f))=C(f)=C(C(f)); \quad \text{and}$$
$$f\circ D(f)=f=C(f)\circ f.$$

$2.$ $g\circ f$ is defined iff $C(f)=D(g).$  If $g\circ f$ is defined then $D(g\circ f)=D(f)$ and $C(g\circ f)=C(g).$  Moreover, if either $(h\circ g)\circ f$ or $h\circ (g\circ f)$ is defined, then both are defined and $(h\circ g)\circ f=h\circ (g\circ f).$
[In fact, given a partial function satisfying $1$ and $2$ we can reconstitute a category, with objects being the identities.]

Questions about notations.

1. In the first definition $\textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}=\coprod_{A,B\in {Obf}\textbf{K}}\textbf{K}(A,B)$, in $\coprod_{A,B\in {Obj}\textbf{K}}$ is it $\coprod$ (coproduct) or $\prod$ (product).  The two symbols look very similar in the book.
2. I am having difficulty understanding the notation $D(D(f))=D(f)=C(D(f))$ because I am having trouble deciphering the sentence: "As before, each $f$ has exactly one identity $u$ such that $u\circ f$ is defined, call it $C(f)$ for the identity of the $\textit{codomain}$ of $f$; and exactly one $v$ such that $f\circ v$ is defined, call it $D(f)$ for the $\textit{domain}$ of $f.$"

I understand both $u,v$ are identity maps/functions where $u$ maps from $A$ to $A$ in $g\circ u=g$ or it is defined as a map from $B$  to $B$ in $u\circ f=f$  But the notation $C(f)$, is it $C(f):=u$ or $C(f):=u:A\to A$ or $C(f):={id}_A,$ which is stem from not able to understand what $\text{identities of } \textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}.$  Same issues apply to how $D(f)$ for $v$ is used.

Thank you in advance

Comment: @ziggurism I am having trouble figuring out how C(D(f))=D(D(f)).

Comment: The domain and codomain of identity coincide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the notation $C(f)$, is it $C(f):=u$ or $C(f):=u:A\to A$ or $C(f):={id}_A,$

They are trying to avoid any mention of objects, to make it all more like a monoid as you see in abstract algebra. That’s why they don’t say $u: A \to A$. As long as you understand that point, that the objects are totally optional, feel free to substitute them if you prefer

$D(f)= D(D(f))$ means the domain of the identity is the same as the domain of any arrow that it may precompose with

> In the first definition $\textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}=\coprod_{A,B\in {Obf}\textbf{K}}\textbf{K}(A,B)$, in $\coprod_{A,B\in {Obj}\textbf{K}}$ is it $\coprod$ (coproduct) or $\prod$ (product)?

The collection of all arrows is viewed as a coproduct (disjoint union) not product, of all the homsets

Comment: When the author says $\text{identities of } \textbf{M}_{\textbf{k}}$, I am not sure if he mean identity maps or an identity element.

Comment: An identity is a multiplicatively neutral element of a monoid or category

Comment: my understanding is that they are treating $C$ and $D$ as functions.  So in the case of $D(f)$, since $f$ maps from $A$ to $B$, then $D(f)={id}_A$.  But then  $C(D(f))=C({id}_A)={id}_A.$  Is that correct?

Comment: @Seth yes that's correct.

Comment: ok ok, thank you so much for your answer.  :)